# Using the "Content Panel" content from PSE in PS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5, photoshop-elements

I own a copy of both Photoshop CS5 and Photoshop Elements. Overall I use PS for everything though I am not a graphic designer and some of the content in PSE is very handy. Mainly the content in the "Content Panel" (see screenshot below) My question is this, is there a way to access that content from within Photoshop CS5. I looked through the Program Files and could not find any of the content. I could go through and save each individual file as a separate PSD and use Bridge to browse those files. Is there a specific file I am missing?

Note: I only looking for the Backgrounds, Frames, and Graphics. The rest I can replicate in PS.

[image: Content Panel in PSE]

[Source of Screenshot](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/PhotoshopElements/8.0/Win/Using/WS0340D7B2-A1B4-4c05-9842-337E6A0D0C83_WIN.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in {all users app data}\Adobe\Photoshop Elements\8.0\Photo Creations for PSE 8. May be different for different PSE versions.

{all users app data} is usually C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data on 2000/XP and C:\ProgramData on Vista/7.

Comment: That is the XP way I believe for Windows 7 it is: `C:\ProgramData\Adobe\Photoshop Elements\10.0\Photo Creations` Substitute the 10.0 above for your version of elements. Note: On windows the Program Data files are hidden files so you'll have to enable Show Hidden, files, folders or drives in the folder options.

Comment: @Lynda I said that, read carefully.

Comment: My apologies =>

Comment: @Lynda You can remove your first comment